# C++11 luabind integration, function failing

Tags: c++, lua, luabind

I'm experimenting with integrating LUA into my program with `luabind`, but I've hit a big stumbling block.

I'm very unfamiliar with LUA's calling conventions and I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Here is my C++ code:

```
struct app_t
{
    //...
    void exit();
    void reset();

    resource_mgr_t resources;
    //...
};

struct resource_mgr_t
{
    //...
    void prune();
    void purge();
    //...
};

extern app_t app;
```

And my `luabind` modules:

```
luabind::module(state)
    [
        luabind::class_<resource_mgr_t>("resource_mgr")
        .def("prune", &resource_mgr_t::prune)
        .def("purge", &resource_mgr_t::purge)
    ];

luabind::module(state)
    [
        luabind::class_<app_t>("app")
        .def("exit", &app_t::exit)
        .def("reset", &app_t::reset)
        .def_readonly("resources", &app_t::resources)
    ];

luabind::globals(state)["app"] = &app;
```

I can execute the following lua commands just fine:

```
app:exit()
app:reset()
```

However, the following call fails:

```
app.resources:purge()
```

With the following error:

```
[string "app.resources:purge()"]:1: attempt to index field 'resources' (a function value)
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[When binding members that are a non-primitive type, the auto generated getter function will return a reference to it.](https://github.com/luabind/luabind/blob/master/doc/docs.rst)

And, just as in `app:reset()`, resources is an instance member field.

So, use it like this:

```
app:resources():purge()
```

Comment: `app:resources():purge()` now yields the run-time error `luabind: property_tag function can't be called`.

Comment: Try `app.resources():purge()`. (I can't test right now.)

Comment: I get the same error :( Apparently I may need to rebuild the luabind libraries. (http://www.gamedev.net/topic/593408-def-readwrite-dosent-work/) I've been running into strange errors with it, such as the mere inclusion of `<luabind/operator.hpp>` causing the program not to compile.

Comment: I did a rebuild of all the libraries, seems a little bit more stable now (e.g. I can use things in `<luabind/operator.hpp>` now). However, I'm still unable to run that command without the same error coming back at me. :/ I remember hearing something about needed to make object wrappers, does that apply here?

Comment: For those who come across this, I ended up going with Python instead of Lua...it's considerably easier to use and better documented.